# Material wont change, but but works on one istance

Tags: lua, roblox

So on my Roblox demo world, im making lights that turn on and off during the day and night, to do so I have a point light and a material change to Neon
but when I try to change it back to Smooth Plastic it won't work

I have tried changing the time it actives, the material, and the greater than/less than a symbol, I am extremely new to code so it may be a simple fix

```
local Lightpart = script.Parent
local PointLight = Lightpart.PointLight

while true do
    wait(0.1)
    if game.Lighting:GetMinutesAfterMidnight() > 18 * 60 then (at 6PM the material will change)
        Lightpart.Material = Enum.Material.Neon
        PointLight.Enable = true
    end
    if game.Lighting:GetMinutesAfterMidnight() > 6 * 60 then  (At 6AM it should change to Plastic
        Lightpart.Material = Enum.Material.Plastic
        PointLight.Enable = false
    end
end
```

So when the time reaches 6Pm at night, the material will change to Neon, but at 6 AM it won't change back
I've even tried just removing the Neon code and it still won't work, it's the same code just with a little change

Answer (score 0):

I think your two if-statements are fighting with each other. If you combine the two statements, you can clarify the logic and fix the light.

```
local Lightpart = script.Parent
local PointLight = Lightpart.PointLight

while true do
    wait(0.1)
    local mins = game.Lighting:GetMinutesAfterMidnight()
    if mins < (6 * 60) or mins > (18 * 60) then
        -- between 6 PM and 6 AM, turn on the lights
        Lightpart.Material = Enum.Material.Neon
        PointLight.Enabled = true
    else
        -- turn off the lights
        Lightpart.Material = Enum.Material.Plastic
        PointLight.Enabled = false
    end
end
```